# Consult a question about subconvexity bounds for symmetric-square L-functions in an Arxiv-eprint due to P. D. Nelson

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

Sorry to disturb, the experts here. Recently, I read a paper of Nelson ("Subconvex equidistribution of cusp forms: reduction to Eisenstein observables--"https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02908.pdf). The paper says that the subconvexity for the twisted symmetric-square L-function $L(s,\text{sym}^2 f\otimes \chi)$ in the level aspect would imply the subconvexity for  $GL_3\times GL_2$ L-functions $L(s, \text{sym}^2 f\otimes g)$ in the level aspect of the newform $f$, where $g$ is a fixed $GL_2$-newform.

My question is: if one has the analogy that the hybrid subconvexity for $L(s,\text{sym}^2 f\otimes \chi)$ in the level and conductor aspects implies that the hybrid subconvexity for $L(s, \text{sym}^2 f\otimes g)$ in both levels aspects of $f,g$?

If any expert here knows something about this, please show me a guide or certain references.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, we don't know this, and there's no reason to expect this to be true.

Comment: Okay, maybe this isn't completely accurate. Say $f$ has squarefree level $q$ and trivial central character, and $g$ is of level $r^2$ (where $(q,r) = 1$) and trivial central character such that there exists a primitive Dirichlet character $\psi$ modulo $r$ such that $g \otimes \psi$ has level $r$. Then it should be possible to prove using currect techniques that hybrid subconvexity for $L(s,\operatorname{sym}^2  f \otimes \chi)$ implies hybrid subconvexity for $L(s,\operatorname{sym}^2 f \otimes g)$. This would be a ton of work, however.

Comment: On the other hand, if instead we assume that $g$ has *squarefree* level $r$ (rather than level $r^2$) and trivial central character, then current techniques no longer work. So there's no systematic treatment.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Dear Humphries, could you please show some references on this, if $g$ is of level $r^2$ as you assumed? On the other hand, I also curious if Nelson's work can be adaptable to show that the level aspect subconvexity of $f$ for $L(\text{sym}^2 f\otimes \chi)$ implies the aspect subconvexity of $f$ for $L(\text{sym}^2 f\otimes g)$, if $\chi$ and $g$ are all allowed to be taken as certain special cases. Great thanks!

Comment: There is no reference; this isn't in the literature. As I said, it would be a ton of work to prove, but is doable by current methods (the strategy is to combine Nelson's work with earlier work of Blomer on subconvexity for twists of selfdual $\mathrm{GL}_3$ $L$-functions, as well as recent work of Petrow-Young). As to your second question, Nelson's paper is quite clear about why his method works and how it does not generalise to other settings.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Okay, thanks for useful explanations.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Dear Humphries, you said if the newform $f$ is of square-free level $q$ with trivial nebentypus, and the form $g$ is of level $r^2$, $(r,q)=1$ with trivial nebentypus, such that there exists a primitive Dirichlet character $\Psi\bmod r$ such that $g\otimes \Psi$ has the level $r$, then this is doable. But, as I know, the level of $g\otimes \Psi$ should be $r^2 $ by H. Iwaniec's topics-book. It seems a little weird.

Comment: No, that's not right. I mean the level of the newform associated to $g \otimes \psi$. For example, let $\widetilde{g}$ be a newform of level $r$ and central character $\psi^2$. Then $g = \widetilde{g} \otimes \overline{\psi}$ has level dividing $r^2$, and $g \otimes \psi = \widetilde{g}$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks for clarification. I still want to know why $g$ must be this form such that we may expect the hybrid subconvexity for $L(s, \text{sym}^2 f\otimes\chi)$ in the level and conductor aspects could imply the hybrid subconvexity for $L(s, \text{sym}^2 f\otimes g)$? Could you show some more underlying reasoning? Sorry to disturb again.

Comment: The whole idea behind the proof is the moment method, which relies on studying moments of families of $L$-functions for which the family is sufficiently small compared to the conductor of the $L$-function. If $g$ has squarefree level $r$, there's no way to make the family small enough while simultaneously using the moment method. In any case, this is probably a discussion best had over email rather than in MO comments.